# Why is printf printing more than size of array?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
char ad[8];
char ct[40];

printf("postal code: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]7s", ad);
printf("city: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]40s", ct);
printf("Address: |%s|%s\n", ad, ct);
```

sample input for ad: `m2r 3r3 t4t`  .
output should be: `m2r 3r3`  .
but
output is: `m2r 3r3 t4t`

Comment: Are you under the impression that `[^\n]7` is a modifier of `%s`?

Comment: @Barmar that is to capture the spaces

Comment: But it's not a modifier. `%[^\n]` is the entire format, `7s` after it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It should be `%7[^\n]`, no `s` after it.

Comment: I've seen people put `s` after `%[^\n]` many times, I don't know where you all get the idea that they're connected.

Comment: @Barmar I tried doing what you said but that skips the next scanf

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why scanf is capturing more than it should

Comment: Since it only reads the first 7 characters, the next scanf will start reading at `t4t`.

Comment: It was capturing more than it should because you didn't have `7` after `%`.

Comment: @Barmar yep I tried that but does not work

Comment: You understand that the next `scanf()` will start reading wherever the previous one stopped, right? So if the first scanf only reads 7 characters, the next one starts reading at character 8, not the next line.

Comment: It's best not to use `scanf()` for user input. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then use `sscanf()` to extract what you want from the line.

Comment: If you must use scanf, always check its return value to see if it suucceded. Well, do that with *any* input function really.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to read 7 characters and discard the rest of the input you can do:

```
char ad[8];
char ct[40];

printf("postal code: ");
scanf("%7s%*[^\n]", ad);
printf("city: ");
scanf("%40s%*[^\n]", ct);
printf("Address: |%s|%s\n", ad, ct);
```

The `%7s` will read 7 characters. And the `%*[^\n]` will read until the end of the line and discard the result.

And just to emphasize, I'm not advocating to use `scanf()` but if you really want to the above code will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot more luck with `fgetc` than with `scanf` although it needs some additional code to work smoothly, this just emphasizes what a hassle user entry can be:

```
char ad[8];
int maxlen = 7;       //must be 1 less than array size for terminator
char a = '0';
int count = 0;
while (a != '\n' && count < maxlen) {   //read until newline or size limit
    a = fgetc(stdin);
    ad[count] = a;
    count++;
}
if (a == '\n') {                   //case: user entry < maxlen
    buffer[count - 1] = '\0';      //get rid of newline char
}
else {                            //case: user entry >= maxlen
    buffer[count] = '\0';         //terminate the string
    do {
        a = fgetc(stdin);
    } while (a != '\n')           //safely flush stdin so next entry works
}
```

Granted this looks like a ridiculous amount of code but you can stick it in a reusable ```getEntry`` function. Also, just avoid user entry if at all possible especially when building your code.  The above so far seems fairly foolproof, at least. It's what I'm now using so any bug-spotting is more than welcome.

Comment: Will try this out from now on